# PHP 5 will not work in Centos 6 for me

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, centos, redhat

Just created a new install of Centos 6.0 64-bit on a virtual machine and running on Vmware workstation 8, windows host.

```
yum install php
service httpd restart
```

And when trying to run a html file from the var\www\html dir
which just has `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in it or pointing browser to localhost. Nothing comes up.

Also opened up httpd.conf and added:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Tried reinstalling, installing php-common, then php etc. to no avail.
Otherwise going for the typical LAMP.

installed:

```
php.x86_64              5.3.2-6.el6_0.1 @updates                                
php-cli.x86_64          5.3.2-6.el6_0.1 @updates                                
php-common.x86_64       5.3.2-6.el6_0.1 @updates
```

Yet to update to Centos 6.1

PHP5 is probably comes installed by default with Centos and I
maybe stuffed it up by running `yum install php`?

Comment: Any relevant httpd logs?

Comment: "And when trying to run a html file" Stupid question, but... does the file have .php extension?

Comment: yeah, just added.

Comment: Is there any php related stuff in /etc/httpd/conf.d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to edit httpd.conf. PHP is includes it's binding from /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf, which is included by **include** directive at httpd.conf. It's enough to check php.conf and ensure that all required lines are not commented. It should work by default with **prefork** httpd. Probably something was wrong with your php.conf.

Answer (score 0):

try to view the source code of the blank page you see, if it has phpinfo present in it, in plain text, that means php module is not working.(which i think wont be a problem).

Also try to turn off selinux, if it works.

check ownership of the file you have created (index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by doing a complete reinstall of the `php` packages.

<sub>According to Question author</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to your php files using short php tags `<?` instead of `<?php`. By default, short tags are not enabled in the php.ini config file.